# Which link I must specify to send attachment in email contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a contact form without file tag. I wanna put in "file attachment" the url of my guide.pdf that I  have put in media wordpress. the url is http://domain.it os the url of file is:

```
http://domanin/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/guide.pdf
```

when I put the link it appears me that the file doesn't exist.
[image]

Anyone can help me?

Comment: http://domanin/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/guide.pdf      http://domain/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/guide.pdf    there is a mistake in your link *domanin - domain*

Comment: @Tomm it doesn't work! if i put the file file path ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact Form 7 3.5 and higher support local file attachment. You can put local file paths in the ‘File attachments’ field and those files will be attached to the email as well as uploaded files.

Put a file path per line. When the path is not an absolute path, it will be treated as a relative path to wp-content directory.

```
uploads/2017/10/guide.pdf
```